# Image req.file.path is undefined on frontend

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, multer, cloudinary

I am using multer and cloudinary for backend to upload image to mongodb and getting req.file.path error and it seems I'm doing something wrong in the frontend when passing image because if I use POSTMAN, the api works and sign ups the user with image as a link.

**Backend Code:**

*controller.js*

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { proImg, role, firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;

  if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !password) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please add all the required fields");
  }

  //Check if the emails already exist
  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });
  const sellerExists = await Seller.findOne({ email });
  if (userExists || sellerExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Email already exists");
  }

  //Hash passwords
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

  //Create user
  const user = await User.create({
    proImg: req.file.path, //Getting error on this line
    role,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user.id,
      proImg: user.proImg,
      role: user.role,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid user data");
  }
});
```

*cloudinary.config.js*

```
  const multer = require("multer");
  const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
  const { CloudinaryStorage } = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");

  const { CLOUDINARY_API, CLOUDINARY_SECRET, CLOUDINARY_HOST } = process.env;
  cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: CLOUDINARY_HOST,
    api_key: CLOUDINARY_API,
    api_secret: CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
  });

  const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params: {
      folder: "images",
      format: async () => "png",
      public_id: (req, file) => file.filename,
    },
  });

  const parser = multer({ storage: storage });

  module.exports = parser;
```

**Frontend:**

*SignupBuyer.jsx*

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    proImg: "",
    role: "buyer",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    cPassword: "",
  });

  const { proImg, role, firstName, lastName, email, password, cPassword } =
    data;

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) toast.error(message);

    if (isSuccess || user) {
      navigate("/buyerdashboard");
    }

    dispatch(reset());
  }, [user, isError, isSuccess, message, navigate, dispatch]);

  //Toggle password display
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);
  const togglePassword = () => {
    setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
  };

  const handleImage = (e) => {
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      proImg: e.target.files[0],
    }));

    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== cPassword) {
      toast.error("Passwords do not match");
    } else {
      const userData = { proImg, role, firstName, lastName, email, password };

      dispatch(register(userData));
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="signup">
        <div className="signup__container">
          <h3>Join Us to Hire Talent</h3>
          <form
            className="signup__container-form"
            encType="multipart/form-data"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
              name="proImg"
              onChange={handleImage}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed the error I was getting and got the expected result. For anyone having a similar problem, I had to change the **handleSubmit** from the frontend from:

```js
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== cPassword) {
      toast.error("Passwords do not match");
    } else {
      const userData = { proImg, role, firstName, lastName, email, password };

      dispatch(register(userData));
    }
  };
```

To this:

```js
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== cPassword) {
      toast.error("Passwords do not match");
    } else {
      const userData = new FormData();
      userData.append("proImg", proImg);
      userData.append("role", role);
      userData.append("firstName", firstName);
      userData.append("lastName", lastName);
      userData.append("email", email);
      userData.append("password", password);

      dispatch(register(userData));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input type has a name property as proImg, looks like you need to specify req.proImg as shown below:

```
proImg: req.proImg.path

    <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg" **name="proImg"** onChange={handleImage}/>
```

Comment: This doesn't works cuz req.file is using multer middleware for uploads. I'm thinking there's something I'm doing wrong in the frontend that's causing it to not work cuz the api works from postman as intended